# can't recognize method in MainActivity on Button Click

Tags: android, listview, button, onclick

I have a **custom layout** for every item in **listview**. But the button in the layout doesn't recognize the activity in **MainActivity**.

The ListView is shown in Main View.
The layout file for each item is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_bookname_listview"
        android:layout_width="234dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_renewed_listview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_delete_book" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_renewed_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Renewed"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:onClick="clickedRenew"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete_book"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btn_renewed_listview"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:onClick="clickedDelete"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The functions are in the MainActivity.java file.
The Functions related to the buttons is as follows:

```
public void clickedRenew(View view)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("Have You renewed the Book?");
    textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

    builder.setCustomTitle(textView)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).create().show();

}


public void clickedDelete(View view)
{
    Log.d("LetMeDelete", "here");
    final View view1 = view;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("Have You retured the book?");
    textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    builder.setCustomTitle(textView)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    View parent = (View) view1.getParent();
                    TextView bookname = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txt_bookname_listview);
                    String bookName = bookname.getText().toString();
                    database.deleteData(bookName);
                    updateListView(database.getAllData());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).create().show();
}

public void updateListView(Cursor data)
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (data.moveToNext())
        {
            arrayList.add(data.getString(1));
        }
        if(arrayAdapter == null)
        {
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_book_name,R.id.txt_bookname_listview, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
        else
        {
            arrayAdapter.clear();
            arrayAdapter.addAll();
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_book_name, R.id.txt_bookname_listview, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        data.close();
        database.close();
    }
```

The **logcat** from android studio is as follows:

```
01-20 04:08:06.081 32344-32344/com.example.imad.bookrenewalert E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.imad.bookrenewalert, PID: 32344
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method clickedDelete(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btn_delete_book'
                                                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:5368)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5327)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I have checked the spellings so many times now, but I can't find any fault. The **clickedDelete** method is fully implemented but **clickedRenew** is not. The Error shown in the `logcat` is after clicking the **Delete** button in **listview** item.

Comment: In which XML, have you placed the button and in which class `clickedDelete` method exists?

Comment: @SrikarReddy I placed the button in a custom layout for showing listview items , the listview is shown in the main layout and these functions are in the MainActivity.Java file.

Comment: You have placed the method in the wrong Java file. I think you might be inflating the custom layout in the adapter. If you are using Recyclerview then you have set click listeners for the individual items in the view holder.

Comment: @SrikarReddy I have used the custom layout in an ArrayAdapter method in MainActivity. But the main layout uses a relativelayout.

Comment: I assume your newest question is an attempt at a workaround for this problem. The issue here is that you're passing `getApplicationContext()` in the `ArrayAdapter` constructors. Don't do that. Pass the `Activity`. That is, `arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, ...);`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank You very much. Please Add this comment as an answer so that I can make it accepted answer.

Comment: No problem. Actually, I'll just close this as a duplicate, since it's been answered here before. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Please do delete your newest question, if this did indeed take care of that issue, as well. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM.Cheers. Okay

Answer (score 0):

**You can solve this problem by another way remove `android:onClick`then use this code in your onCreate method after initializing the buttons:**

```
firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textView.setText("Have You renewed the Book?");
textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

builder.setCustomTitle(textView)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).create().show();
    });
```

**and for the second button use:**

```
secondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View view) {
 Log.d("LetMeDelete", "here");
    final View view1 = view;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("Have You retured the book?");
    textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    builder.setCustomTitle(textView)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    View parent = (View) view1.getParent();
                    TextView bookname = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.txt_bookname_listview);
                    String bookName = bookname.getText().toString();
                    database.deleteData(bookName);
                    updateListView(database.getAllData());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).create().show();
    });
```

Comment: I initialized the button inside onCreate like this
**deleteBook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_book);** But this creates an error "attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Comment: did you delete onClick and did you set setContentView(R.layout.main) to your Main Layout ?

Comment: I deleted onClick attributes on the xml file. I also set setContentView for MainActivity inside the onCreate.

Comment: I can provide you a link of the current state of the project as this is in github and I am doing this project for learning android.

Comment: Ok let check it please

Comment: The project link on github is https://github.com/imad062/BookRenewAlert.git

Comment: your activity_main layout doesn't contain on delete and renew buttons

Comment: The buttons are in the custom layout named **item_book_name.xml**. The issue in this problem has been resolved. I was passing the context via getApplicationContext() in listAdapter. This resulted in the listview not identifying the methods. Thank you for helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to hear that. you are welcome.